# Moving an ImageView located in a WindowManager doesn't work properly

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener, android-windowmanager

I'm trying to draw an Icon over everything on the screen (TOP MOST) similar to the chathead of new Facebook messenger

I have create a service to work in the background and based on a specific condition my icon should appear on the screen (exactly like when someone sends you a message on facebook the messenger service will hook the message and shows the chathead on the screen to notify you about the new message)

**What I did:**

I have created the service and gave it the permission to show system alert windows (since the head is actually a system alert window)

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = Android.Manifest.Permission.SystemAlertWindow)]
```

I have inherited a class (StickyHeadView) from ImageView and implemented OnTouchListener listener using the following way :

```
class StickyHeadView : ImageView, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
{
    private StickyHeadService OwnerService;

    public StickyHeadView(StickyHeadService ContextService, Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        OwnerService = ContextService;
        SetOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    float TouchMoveX;
    float TouchMoveY;

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        var windowService = OwnerService.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WindowService);
        var windowManager = windowService.JavaCast<Android.Views.IWindowManager>();

        switch (e.Action & e.ActionMasked)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                TouchMoveX = (int)e.GetX();
                TouchMoveY = (int)e.GetY();
                OwnerService.LOParams.X = (int)(TouchMoveX);
                OwnerService.LOParams.Y = (int)(TouchMoveY);
                windowManager.UpdateViewLayout(this, OwnerService.LOParams);                    
                Log.Debug("Point : ", "X: " + Convert.ToString(OwnerService.LOParams.X) + " Y: " + Convert.ToString(OwnerService.LOParams.Y));
                return true;                    
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                return true;                    
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The service has wiindow manager to show the Icon on it...in Service "OnStart" event I initialize the Head :

```
        private StickyHeadView MyHead;
        public Android.Views.WindowManagerLayoutParams LOParams;
        public override void OnStart(Android.Content.Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            base.OnStart(intent, startId);

            var windowService = this.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WindowService);
            var windowManager = windowService.JavaCast<Android.Views.IWindowManager>();

            MyHead = new StickyHeadView(this, this);
            MyHead.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
            LOParams = new Android.Views.WindowManagerLayoutParams(Android.Views.WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
                                Android.Views.WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent,
                                Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.Phone,
                                Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable,
                                Android.Graphics.Format.Translucent);

            LOParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top | GravityFlags.Left;
            LOParams.X = 10;
            LOParams.Y = 10;
            windowManager.AddView(MyHead, LOParams);
        }
```

as you can see I have declared a WindowManager and added the view (MyHead) to it with special parameters

**My Problem :**

When ever I try to move the View (My head) it doesn't move in a stable way and keeps having a quake!

I'm testing it using android 4.0.4 on real HTC Phone

I'm using monodroid

Please help...if the implementation of the touch is not right please suggest a better way...thank you.

Comment: Why no body is replying! i guess it is a forum for questions!!!!

Comment: is that java? what compiler do you use?

Answer (score 6):

In your code just use...

```
TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
```

or

```
TYPE_PHONE
```

**instead of**

```
TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY
```

Hope this will help you.

a working example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, //TYPE_PHONE
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

    chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          private int initialX;
          private int initialY;
          private float initialTouchX;
          private float initialTouchY;

          @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = params.x;
                initialY = params.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                return true;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                return true;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The e.GetX()/eGetY() you are using is relative to view position so when you move the view with UpdateViewLayout the next values will be relative to the move. It works using GetRawX()/GetRawY(), but you have to keep track of the initial Down rawX and rawY also.

Here is my JAVA that works:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            layoutParams.x = Math.round(event.getRawX() - downX);
            layoutParams.y = Math.round(event.getRawY() - downY);
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatingView, layoutParams);
            return true;                    
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downX = event.getRawX() - layoutParams.x;
            downY = event.getRawY() - layoutParams.y;
            return true;                    
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

One comment, there's a big downside in using windowManager.updateViewLayout(...) this method will call onLayout on the floating view for each move, and that might be a performance issue, anyway until now I haven't found another method to move the floating view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this might be help ful

first add global variable on your activity:

```
    WindowManager wm;
    LinearLayout lay;
    float downX,downY;
```

after put in code to oncreate on your activity

```
    Button btnstart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btnstop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(lay==null)
            {
                wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                params.x = (int) wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                params.y = 0;
                // params.height = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/2;
                params.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

                params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
                params.setTitle("Info");

                lay = null;

                lay = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                lay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                // lay.setAlpha(0.5f);

                TextView txt_no = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                txt_no.setTextSize(10.0f);
                txt_no.setText("Moving view by stack user!");

                txt_no.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                // txt_no.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                // LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); // margins as you wish

                txt_no.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                txt_no.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                txt_no.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                txt_no.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

                lay.addView(txt_no);

                AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.5F, 0.5F);
                alpha.setDuration(0); // Make animation instant
                alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends
                // And then on your layout
                wm.addView(lay, params);
                txt_no.startAnimation(alpha);

                downX=params.x;
                downY=params.y;

                Log.v("MSES>", "x="+ downX +",y="+ downY);

                lay.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                            params.x = Math.round(event.getRawX() - downX);
                            params.y = Math.round(event.getRawY() - downY);
                            wm.updateViewLayout(lay, params);
                            Log.v("MSES EVENT>", "x="+ event.getRawX() +",y="+ event.getRawY());
                            Log.v("MSES MOVE>", "x="+ params.x +",y="+ params.y);
                            return true;                    
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            downX = event.getRawX() - params.x;
                            downY = event.getRawY() - params.y;
                            Log.v("MSES DOWN>", "x="+ params.x +",y="+ params.y);
                           return true;                    
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            //params.x = Math.round(event.getRawX() - downX);
                            //params.y = Math.round(event.getRawY() - downY);
                            //wm.updateViewLayout(lay, params);
                            return true;                   

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });

    btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (lay != null) {
                lay.removeAllViews();
                wm.removeViewImmediate(lay);
                lay = null;
            }
        }
    });
```